# Tornado: How to send default file if not found in StaticFileHandler

Tags: tornado

When a requested static file is not found, I want to send back a default file. eg. `/images/dog.png` -> `/images/default.png`.

After digging into the source code [here](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/_modules/tornado/web.html#StaticFileHandler.validate_absolute_path).

```
if (os.path.isdir(absolute_path) and
    self.default_filename is not None):
```

Setting `default_filename` is used for request like `/images/` -> `/images/default.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting `validate_absolute_path` function, why not override this to provide your default file if not exist ?

```py
import tornado 
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop

import os

DEFAULT_ABSPATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

class StaticFileOrDefaultHandler(tornado.web.StaticFileHandler):

    def validate_absolute_path(self, root, absolute_path):
        try:
            return super(StaticFileOrDefaultHandler, self).validate_absolute_path(root, absolute_path)
        except tornado.web.HTTPError as e:
            if e.status_code == 404:
                return os.path.join(DEFAULT_ABSPATH, 'default.png')
            raise e


app = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/(.*)', StaticFileOrDefaultHandler, { 'path': DEFAULT_ABSPATH }),
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

#### edit

To avoid override `HTTPError(403)` check with the `status_code` if the raised error is a `404`.